# php - Replace string with int

Tags: php

I have made my own array with all the letters, numbers and most of the symbols and given each one a number for exemple 'a' = 19; How do I replace the $string letters/numbers with the numbers in the array so that $newString = 19202122 for example?

```
$string = 'abcd';

$stringList = array(
    19 => 'a',
    20 => 'b',
    21 => 'c',
    22 => 'd',
};

$newString = 19202122;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You should flip your array around, `'a' => 19` and so on.

Comment: I'm really bad at php and trying to learn, I have been looking how to do it but I could not find anyting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the array the other way and use the `strtr()` function like this:

```
$string = 'abcd';

$stringList = array(
    'a' => 19,
    'b' => 20,
    'c' => 21,
    'd' => 22,
);

$newString = strtr($string, $stringList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions str_replace, array_keys and array_values.
Like that:

```
$string = 'abcd';

$stringList = array(
    19 => 'a',
    20 => 'b',
    21 => 'c',
    22 => 'd',
};
$newString =  str_replace(array_values($stringList), array_keys($stringList), $string);
echo $newString; // 19202122
```

Comment: It would be more readable and also more efficient, if the array was not defined in the style of replacement => needle. See my comment for an example

Comment: @MartinCernac Well you are right but I wanted to keep the author's array, we don't know how and from where he got it.

Comment: Well he mentioned, that "he made his own array" so I based my answer on that. Anyway your solution is clearly easier to implement, since it's a drop-in.

Comment: how can I make it in a more efficient way?

Comment: @Michael check my answer. It is more efficient, because it doesn't have to modify the array, it just uses it as you define it.

Answer (score 1):

Use str_replace with arrays:

```
$letters = array('a','b','c','d');
$numbers = array(19,20,21,22);
$newString = str_replace($letters,$numbers,$string);
```